# How to find out difference between directory and svn checkout?

Tags: svn

I want to know

How to find out difference between normal mkdir directory and svn checkout directory?

Comment: An svn checkout has a (hidden) folder called `.svn` in it. That's it.

Comment: Try google. I'd start by googling "_svn current changes_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have svn installed, it's very easy: just execute `svn status` inside the directory in question and it will tell if you if the current folder is a working copy or not.

If you do not have svn installed, you need to check for a `.svn` folder. Note, however, that since svn 1.7 only the root node of a svn working copy contains the `.svn` folder.

**Update**

If you need to check multiple directories at once, you can try this command:

```bsh
for dir in dirs_to_check; do
  svn info && echo $dir
done
```

This will print out all svn directories. `dirs_to_check` should be a space-separated list of directories, e.g.

```
/home/user/proj1 /home/user/proj2 /home/user/proj3
```

Comment: but if I have lot of directories to check. I can't be going inside each directory and type svn status. some command which lists all working copies.

Answer (score 0):

`mkdir` fails to create the necessary extra configuration information to tie the directory back to a subversion repository.

As a result, the directory created with `mkdir` will not be under revision control when you attempt to perform other subversion actions (with the exception of add and import, which assume a directory not under subversion control).

`svn checkout ...` will effectively also call (internally) the `mkdir` routines; however, in addition it also makes other items (.svn directories and files) which "add" subversion configuration details to a directory tree.  As such, subsequent subversion commands find these additional bits of information and can use them to make network connections and report on the relative up-to-date-ness of your local copy of the repository.